# if nan python pandas loop

Tags: pandas, loops, if-statement

This is a bit weird and I don't have a sample data frame but if anyone can help that would be great.

I have 3 columns A, B and C.

C might be blank / nan.

I was to say, if C is blank and A and B equal the same values as A and B of the row above. Then set C to the same value as C of the row above.

this is what I have so far. Its running but not changing the values of C.

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():

    if df['C'][i]==np.nan:
        if df[['A','B']][i]==df[['A','B']][i-1]:
            df['C'][i]=df['C'][i-1]
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
```

Does anyone see why this might not be working?

Many thanks

I've also tried this but this code is not working at all

```
 for i, row in df.iterrows():

    if df['C'][i]==np.nan & df[['A','B']][i]==df[['A','B']][i-1]:
            df['C'][i]=df['C'][i-1]

    else:
        pass
```

so df:

```
A    B    C
w    4    t
w    4
a   r     c
```

Output should be :

```
  A    B    C
    w    4    t
    w    4    t
    a   r     c
```

Comment: Got the answer thanks to the guys below. If anyone see what's wrong with the loop please do comment, as I'm really curious now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [DataFrame.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(0, 20, size = 100),
                  'B': np.random.randint(0, 20, size = 100),
                   'C':np.random.randint(0, 20, size = 100)})

   A    B   C
0   9   0   16
1   15  15  13
2   9   1   4
3   14  13  18
4   4   14  10



df['C'] = np.where((df['A'] == df['A'].shift(1)) & (df['B'] == df['B'].shift(1))& (df['C'] == np.nan), df['C_shift'], df['C'])

np.sum(df['C'] == df['C'].shift(
>>3
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot

Comment: @fred.schwartz Happy to help :}

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df['C'] = np.where((df['A']==df['A'].shift()) & (df['B']==df['B'].shift()) & (df['C'].isnull()), df['C'].shift(), df['C'] )
```